# Can an Eldritch Knight replace their 1st-level spell acquired through Magic Initiate (Wizard)?

Tags: dnd-5e, spells, feats, retraining, eldritch-knight

In the *Player Handbook*, under ***Spells Known of 1st-Level and Higher*** for the Eldritch Knight Fighter archetype, it states that:

> Whenever you gain a level in this class, you can replace one of the
>   wizard spells you know with another spell of your choice from the
>   wizard spell list. The new spell must be of a level for which you have
>   spell slots, and it must be an abjuration or evocation spell, unless
>   you’re replacing the spell you gained at 3rd, 8th, 14th, or 20th level
>   from any school of magic *(75)*.

So, I've got a few questions here...

1. If you choose the wizard version of the Magic Initiate feat and know a wizard spell that way, can you replace it at a higher level if you were so inclined?
2. And if so, would replacing it be limited by the archetype's spellcasting feature, or would you be able to pick any spell since you learned it via extraordinary means?

I DM on the regular and know how I'd rule at the table ("yes" and "limited to the rules in the spellcasting feature"), but I'm curious to see if the community knows something I don't.